# Using prepared statement in Groovy

Tags: sql, groovy, prepared-statement, soapui, getproperty

this is for testing purposes (automatic testing) SoapUI

```
def status = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "Status" )
def grid = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "Grid" )+"_V"
def grid1

if (["TABLE1","TABLE2"].contains(grid))
     grid1 ="HUBCFG."+grid
else grid1 = "SDM."+grid
```

> > Option1
>
> ```
> sql.executeUpdate "UPDATE " +grid1+" t0 set XXX='$status' WHERE t0.YYY='$grid'"
> ```
>
> > Option2
>
> ```
> String bql = "UPDATE $grid1 t0 set XXX='$status' WHERE t0.YYY='$grid'"
> sql.executeUpdate bql
> ```

```
sql.commit()
log.info("Successfully committed "+grid1+ " To " + status)
```

i didnt find the answers clear cut anywhere, so i scraped them together.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: nope, i solved it myself. felt like sharing. 
i guess the question would be, are there any improvements you see possible ?

Comment: This sort of coding in Oracle **don't use bind variabales** leading to a statement such es `UPDATE tupd t0 set XXX='xxx' WHERE t0.YYY='1'`. I.e. the statement will be hard parsed for each execution.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
sql.executeUpdate "UPDATE ${Sql.expand(grid1)} t0 set XXX=$status WHERE t0.YYY=$grid"
```

Or

```
def bql = "UPDATE ${Sql.expand(grid1)} t0 set XXX=$status WHERE t0.YYY=$grid"
```

The single quotes will be added for you, and Sql.expand allows you to embed things like table names into the resultant templated Groovy String

Comment: This is prefered coding using Groovy SQL - **no quoted strings are added but bind variables are used**,  such as `UPDATE tupd t0 set XXX=:1  WHERE t0.YYY=:2`. Unfortunately Groovy SQL doesn't support prepareStatement, so the query will be *soft* parsed on each execution.