# How can I prevent sql injection with groovy?

Tags: groovy, sql-injection

I have a sql like:

```
String sql = """SELECT id, name, sex, age, bron_year, address, phone, state, comment, is_hbp, is_dm, is_cva, is_copd, is_chd, is_cancer, is_floating, is_poor, is_disability, is_mental
 FROM statistics_stin WHERE 1=1
 ${p.team_num == 0 ? "" : "AND team_num = ${p.team_num}"}
 ${p.zone == 0 ? "" : "AND team_id = ${p.zone}"}
 ${p.is_hbp == 2 ? "" : "AND is_hbp = ${p.is_hbp}"}
 ${p.is_dm == 2 ? "" : "AND is_dm = ${p.is_dm}"}
 ${p.is_chd == 2 ? "" : "AND is_chd = ${p.is_chd}"}
 ${p.is_cva == 2 ? "" : "AND is_cva = ${p.is_cva}"}
 ${p.is_copd == 2 ? "" : "AND is_copd = ${p.is_copd}"}
 ${p.is_cancer == 2 ? "" : "AND is_cancer = ${p.is_cancer}"}
 ${p.is_floating == 2 ? "" : "AND is_floating = ${p.is_floating}"}
 ${p.is_poor == 2 ? "" : "AND is_poor = ${p.is_poor}"}
 ${p.is_disability == 2 ? "" : "AND is_disability = ${p.is_disability}"}
 ${p.is_mental == 2 ? "" : "AND is_mental = ${p.is_mental}"}
 ${p.is_aged == 2 ? "" : (p.is_aged == 1 ? " AND age >= 65" : " AND age < 65")}
 ${p.is_prep_aged == 2 ? "" : (p.is_prep_aged == 1 ? "AND (age BETWEEN 60 AND 64)" : "AND (age < 60 OR age > 64)")}
 ${p.is_young == 2 ? "" : (p.is_young == 1 ? " AND age < 60" : " AND age >= 60")}
 ORDER BY team_id ASC, id ASC
 LIMIT ${start}, ${page_size}
 """;
```

Then use :

```
def datasource = ctx.lookup("jdbc/mysql");
def executer = Sql.newInstance(datasource);
def rows = executer.rows(sql);
```

Here the p is a json object like:

```
p = {is_aged=2, is_cancer=2, is_chd=1, is_copd=2, is_cva=2, is_disability=2, is_dm=2, is_floating=2, is_hbp=1, is_mental=2, is_poor=2, pn=1, team_num=0, zone=0}
```

This way has sql injection. I know I can use params type like:

```
executer.rows('SELECT * from statistics_stin WHERE is_chd=:is_chd', [is_chd: 1]);
```

But this case has to many AND conditions, use or not will be decided by the json p.

How to do this please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782702/using-prepared-statement-in-groovy

Comment: @metters Thank you, but I do not think it can prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem of dynamic SQL binding, i.e. the number of bind parameters is not constant, but depend on the input.

There is an elegant solution from [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/oramag/on-popularity-and-natural-selection.html)
which has even more elegant implementation in Groovy

The basic idea is simple bind **all variables**, the variables that have an input value and should be used are processed normally, e.g

```
 col1 = :col1
```

the variables that have no input (and shall be ignored) are binded with a dummy construct:

```
 (1=1 or :col2 is NULL)
```

i.e. they are effectively ignored by shortcut evaluation.

Here two examples for three columns

```
 def p = ["col1" : 1, "col2" : 2, "col3" : 3]
```

This input leads to a full query

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
 FROM tab WHERE
 col1 = :col1 AND
 col2 = :col2 AND
 col3 = :col3
ORDER by col1,col2,col3
```

For limited input

```
 p = [ "col3" : 3]
```

you get this query

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
 FROM tab WHERE
 (1=1 or :col1 is NULL) AND
 (1=1 or :col2 is NULL) AND
 col3 = :col3
ORDER by col1,col2,col3
```

Here the Groovy creation of the SQL Statement

```
String sql = """SELECT col1, col2, col3
 FROM tab WHERE   
 ${(!p.col1) ? "(1=1 or :col1 is NULL)" : "col1 = :col1"} AND
 ${(!p.col2) ? "(1=1 or :col2 is NULL)" : "col2 = :col2"} AND
 ${(!p.col3) ? "(1=1 or :col3 is NULL)" : "col3 = :col3"}  
ORDER by col1,col2,col3
"""
```

You can even get rid of the ugly `1=1` predicate;)

Comment: Thank you. by this way, it can work, even sql is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to build your bindings as you build the query then execute the appropriate implementation of `rows`

```
def query = new StringBuilder( "SELECT id, name, sex, age, bron_year, address, phone, state, comment, is_hbp, is_dm, is_cva, is_copd, is_chd, is_cancer, is_floating, is_poor, is_disability, is_mental FROM statistics_stin WHERE 1=1" )
def binds = []
if ( p.team_num == 0 ) {
    query.append( ' AND team_num = ? ' )
    binds << p.team_num
}
if ( p.zone == 0 ) {
    query.append( ' AND team_id = ? ' )
    binds << p.zone == 0
}
...
executer.rows(query.toString(), binds);
```

Comment: Nice alternative with building the bind array.